# Загрузить данные из csv файла в таблицу

Tags: phpmyadmin, php, mysql

Добрый день, подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём проблема, есть CSV-файл, мне нужно данные из него загрузить в таблицу, но почему-то они не загружаются. Собственно вот часть кода, которая загружает

```
    do {
            mysql_query("insert into shop_tovar (cros, article, name, price, balance,manufacturer,is_postavshik, created_at, updated_at, auto_add) 
                values (
                    '".addslashes($data[2])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[2])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[5])."',
                    11,
                    11,
                    '".addslashes($data[1])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[1])."',
                    ".time().",
                    ".time().",
                    0)");

    } while ($data = fgetcsv($file,1000,",","'"));
    echo 'finish!';
```

Мне кажется, что я как-то неправильно оформил запрос к БД, но когда я через PhpMyAdmin, делаю этот запрос (естественно подставляя данные из файла), то всё записывается.

Подскажите, в чём может быть проблема. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сказал больше - а пробовали ли вы вывести хотя бы один сгенерированный SQL?

Это во-первых, а во вторых - при первом проходе какие данные есть в $data? Че-то мне кажется, что там пусто.

Попробуйте сделать так:

```
while ($data = fgetcsv($file,1000,",","'")) {
    $sql = "...";
    echo $sql;    // <- потом удалить
    die();        // <- потом удалить
    mysql_query($sql);
}
```

И посмотрите что за SQL вы генерируете. Вполне возможно, что только смена do...while на while...do поможет. Если нет - увидите что не так с SQL.

И, кстати, а что если в CSV будет 10^6 записей (ну или даже 10^3)? Будете миллион раз писать в БД?

Может стоит читать данные порцией и затем порцией вставлять? Т.е. SQL типа:

```
INSERT INTO ... (...) VALUES
    (...), (...), ...
```

Ну и в коде:

```
$resultData = array();
while ($data = fgetcsv($file,1000,",","'")) {
    $resultData[] = $data;
    if (count($resultData)) == PORTINON_COUNT) {
        process_update($resultData);
        $resultData = array();
    }
}
process_update($resultData);
```

Последний update - чтобы остатки CSV обновить.

Comment: спасибо всем за ответы! помогло разобраться))